Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) macro VBA in excel
I got sent an excel file where file names are inserted from a folder, it converts it to a new name, If there are duplicates, i rename them with a different follow number. But when i try to rewrite the names of the files names in the folder, i got an error message.
Sub RenameFiles()

Dim myPath As String
myPath = "/Users/kenny/Documents/Foto/"

r = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(r, 2))
    Name myPath & Cells(r, 1).Value As myPath & Cells(r, 2).Value
    r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub

It gives the error on the line 'Name myPath & Cells(r, 1).Value As myPath & Cells(r, 2).Value'
Some extra info: I got this from a windows computer with excel 2016 (i think) and i got a mac with office 365 excel.
I tried adjusting some things, but new to VBA.

What is the content of Cell(r, 1) when the error occurs and does a file with that name exist in the directory? Watch for leading or trailing spaces which may cause the problem.

Your loop will be executed until the cells of both columns are empty. If only one of the cells is empty, the name command will be executed but it will miss either the old or the new name.

Sorry i am new to this, how can i check what content it has?

@FunThomas the cells and columns are both filled.  And the first 5-10 are done correctly and after that i will get this error

"How can I check what content is has" - learn to use the debugger. Execute the code step by step (using F8). Hover over the term that you want to check, or use the Watch Window or the Local Window, or use Debug.Print. Invest the 20min and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um2JwZfwoFI&t=66s

I found a new code to work around the error. Apparently it was because of the special letters, symbols like é, è, etc.
I wrote this code.
Sub RenameFiles()

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim oldName As String
    Dim newName As String
    
    myPath = "/Users/kenny/Documents/Foto/"
    
    r = 2
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Error handling inschakelen
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) And IsEmpty(Cells(r, 2))
        oldName = myPath & Cells(r, 1).Value
        newName = myPath & Cells(r, 2).Value
        
        ' Controleer of het doelbestand al bestaat
        If Dir(newName) <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Bestand " & newName & " bestaat al. Rij: " & r
            r = r + 1
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        
        ' Probeer het bestand te hernoemen
        Name oldName As newName
        
    NextIteration:
        r = r + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Alle bestanden zijn succesvol hernoemd."
    Exit Sub
    
    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Er is een fout opgetreden bij het hernoemen van bestand in rij " & r & ". Fout: " & Err.Description
    Resume NextIteration
End Sub

But now i need something for the file names with those special signs. How can i incorporate those, so they will change also in the same script?
